# Serving a static file from a specific URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, routes, asset-pipeline

Suppose I have a file "example.txt", which lives in my assets/files folder in my Rails app. On production, I can access this file via the url '/assets/example.txt'

How can I set up my routes.rb file so that I can access the contents of example.txt when I simply visit 'example.txt'?

Comment: You can simply put the file in your public folder and it would be available at 'example.com/example.txt'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest method is to place the file in your public directory. By default this serves static assets in most cases.

Comment: Important addition: The path to the file in the **URL** is just **root "/"**, not "/public/"
Example URL: `http://myserver.com/example.txt`.